# count number of files with same content in 2 different folders in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have 2 folders in my unix, named folderA and folderB with 5 files each

```
FolderA              FolderB
file1                file1
file2                file2
file3                file3
file4                file4
file5                file5
```

> Assume file1,file2 contents in both the folders are same

I need output as "The 2 directories has 2 files with same content and 3 files with different content"

Also the file names in both directories are same and number of files in both directories would be same in number(no special scenarios).
I did something like this

```
diff -U 0 /FolderA /FolderB | grep -v ^@ | wc -l
```

*I got output as 22* and i think this is for all the differences in all the files. 
somehow i need to get each file differences and write for and if condition to get count. I am fairly new to Unix, so unable to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the files that differ

```
diff -qrs dir1 dir2 | grep differ | wc -l
```

To get the files that are identical

```
diff -qrs dir1 dir2 | grep identical | wc -l
```

Comment: wow..awesome its working. I want to assign this to a variable and print. So i did this.  ** a = $(diff -qrs dir1 dir2 | grep differ | wc -l )    echo "The files that differ is $a" **. If you can help me in figuring it out, will mark this as answer..Thanks for your valuable time and effort. I appreciate for your help.

Comment: To assign it to a variable just include the command within backtics (  " ` ").  Have a look at (http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-bsd-appleosx-bash-assign-variable-command-output/)

Comment: Thanks @Nuetrino for your time and help

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

f1="FolderA"
f2="FolderB"

cd "$f1" || exit 1
for i in file*; do if diff "$i" "../$f2/$i" >/dev/null; then ((same++)); else ((diff++)); fi; done

echo "$same files with same content and $diff files with different content"
```

Output:

```
2 files with same content and 3 files with different content
```

Comment: Sorry, i did not try this. Thanks for your time and effort